# launch.json in vscode for parcel and vanilla js

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, parceljs

I am trying to debug a program I am working on but I can't get the launch.json to work so that my breakpoints bind. I am using parcel for a server. Everything is in the root directory. I want to run my program from index.js. I am very confused and would appreciate the help. I am attaching a screenshot of my file directory and I will post my launch.json and package.json below. Thank you!

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\index.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json

```
{
  "name": "dumbed-down-pacman",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Laila Naseeb",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.22.5",
    "parcel": "^2.9.2"
  }
}
```

package.json

I tried using the prebuilt launch.json for node and for chrome and neither of them worked. My breakpoints would not bind. It would point out where I had put the breakpoint but that it could not find the file.